# Как передать данные из одного приложение в другое

Tags: java

Допустим есть главное приложение, мне нужно передать данные из БД в другое приложение. Как это сделать?

Comment: Чисто наугад... RabbitMQ?

Comment: Чисто наугад... Записав в базу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть миллион способов - через файл, через сокет, через Web-service, по e-mail, через шину и пр. Общая концепция такая - ваше приложение должно "положить" куда-то данные в формате понятном другому приложению, откуда это другое приложение должно "забрать" эти данные.